# Need help for playing Audiofiles in sequence for talking clock - react-native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, audio-player

I have rediscovered React Native and would like to learn how to develop a native app. For learning, I will create a speaking clock.
The time and date are already programmed, shown on-screen, and are updated every second.
I want one button to announce the current time and the second, the date.

I have the audio files with speaking numbers from 00 to 59. The words "It is", "and" and "o'clock".
I have problems understanding the audio part. I can play individual audio files, but I can't get multiple files to be played one after the other.
Does anyone have an idea or a solution?

My previous code looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  Button,
  Alert,
  NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';

import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

//Audio-Library
import useSound from 'react-native-use-sound';

const Section = ({ children, title }): Node => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}
      >
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}
      >
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

function Wochentag(tag = 0) {
  var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  return days[tag];
}

function Monat(m = 0) {
  var months = [
    '',
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ];
  return months[m];
}

function Digit(d = 0) {
  if (d < 10) d = '0' + d;
  return d;
}

class Uhr extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: Digit(new Date().getHours()) + ':' + Digit(new Date().getMinutes()),
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      time: Digit(new Date().getHours()) + ':' + Digit(new Date().getMinutes()),
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.state.time}</Text>;
  }
}

class Datum extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datum: Digit(new Date().getDate()) + ' ' + Monat(new Date().getMonth() + 1) + ' ' + new Date().getFullYear(),
      wtag: Wochentag(new Date().getDay()),
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      datum: Digit(new Date().getDate()) + ' ' + Monat(new Date().getMonth() + 1) + ' ' + new Date().getFullYear(),
      wtag: Wochentag(new Date().getDay()),
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        {this.state.wtag}, {this.state.datum}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  //Play Audio
  const path = 'test.wav';
  const [play, pause, stop, data] = useSound(path, {
    timeRate: 100,
    playbackRate: 1000,
    volume: 1.0,
  });

  const onPress = () => {
    if (!data.isPlaying) play();
    else {
      stop();
    }
  };

  const PlayFile = <Button title={data.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'} onPress={() => onPress()} />;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
      <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" style={backgroundStyle}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}
        >
          <Section title="Aktuelle Uhrzeit ist: ">
            <Uhr /> Uhr
          </Section>
          <Section title="Heute ist: ">
            <Datum />
          </Section>
          <Section title=""></Section>

          <Button
            title="Uhrzeit ansagen"
            onPress={() => Alert.alert('Noch wird die Uhrzeit nicht angesagt. das kommt aber sehr bald....')}
          />

          <Button
            title="Datum ansagen"
            onPress={() => Alert.alert('Noch wird das Datum nicht angesagt. das kommt aber sehr bald....')}
          />

          {PlayFile}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Maybe someone has an idea how to use the following example for my problem.
[HTML5 audio tag in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033228/html5-audio-tag-in-react)

New Update:
this code is working, but not optimal. Have someone an Idea for better solution?

```js
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

function Digit(d=0) {
if(d < 10) d = '0' + d;
return d;
}

function AudioClock(datei) {
Sound.setCategory('Playback');
var audioFile = new Sound(datei, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
    return;
  }

  // loaded successfully
  console.log('duration in seconds: ' + audioFile.getDuration() + 'number of channels: ' + audioFile.getNumberOfChannels());


  audioFile.setVolume(1);
audioFile.setPan(1);

 audioFile.play((success) => {
    if (success) {
      console.log('successfully finished playing');
    } else {
      console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
    }
  });
});

...

const SayTime = () => {
setTimeout( () => AudioClock('it_is.wav'), 10); // it is
setTimeout( () => AudioClock('uhr_' + Digit(new Date().getHours()) +'.wav'), 900); // hours
setTimeout(() => AudioClock('and.wav'), 1400); // and
setTimeout( () => AudioClock('uhr_' + Digit(new Date().getMinutes()) + '.wav'), 2000); // minutes
setTimeout( () => AudioClock('o_clock.wav'), 3100); // o'clock
};

...

      <Button
        title="Say time"
        onPress={SayTime}
      />`
```

Comment: I tried that with the following update/change.
...
```typescript
function SayTime(file=0) {
var path = './' + file + ".wav";
  const [play, pause, stop, data] = useSound(path, {
    timeRate: 100,
    playbackRate: 1000,
    volume: 1.0,
  });
}

...

const onPress = () => {
var hur = Digit(new Date().getHours());
var minutes = Digit(new Date().getMinutes();

SayTime('it_is');
SayTime(hours);
SayTime('and');
SayTime(minutes);
SayTime('oclock');
};

...

          <Button
            title="Uhrzeit ansagen"
            onPress={() => onPress()}
          /> ```

Comment: Maybe someone has an idea how to use the following example for my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033228/html5-audio-tag-in-react

Comment: new working code added. please help to fix that for better solution work.